# How to create this table for multi-line rotated text and thick vertical lines?

Tags: tables, rules, multirow

I want to create the table below and I am not sure how to do it.

I also want the lines that say, "Long line of text really long" to be wrapped, and take up 2 instead of 1 so that the table isn't as long. I want this table to fit in a column of a 2 column paper.

I included an arrow in the picture because I want that first vertical line to be thick also and I don't know how to do it.

I also want the horizontal line below the columns 2-9 to be bold.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\RotText[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2cm}{\centering#1}}}

\newlength{\arrayrulewidthOriginal}
\newcommand{\Cline}[2]{%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidthOriginal}{\arrayrulewidth}}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{#1}}\cline{#2}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\arrayrulewidthOriginal}}}

\begin{document}

{
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|Y!{\vrule width 1pt}Y|Y|Y|Y|Y!{\vrule width 1pt}Y|Y|Y|Y|}
\cline{2-10}
\multicolumn{1}{c!{\vrule width 1pt}}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c!{\vrule width 1pt}}{Some text}  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Some text} \\
\cline{2-10}
\multicolumn{1}{c!{\vrule width 1pt}}{} & \RotText{Some really long text} & \RotText{Some really long text}
  & \RotText{Some really long text} & \RotText{Some really long text} 
  & \RotText{Some really long text} & \RotText{Some really long text} 
  & \RotText{Some really long text} & \RotText{Some really long text} 
  & \RotText{Some really long text} \\
\noalign{\hrule height 1pt}
some text & 11 & 44 & 11 & 54 & 34 & 54 & 23 & 11 & 12 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A close-up to the table:

[image]

#### Some explanatory comments:

- You can produce vertical rules of the desired thickness using `!{\vrule width 1pt}` instead of `|` (change `1pt` to the desired value).
- You can produce horizontal rules (similar to `\hline`) of the desired thickness using `\noalign{\hrule height 1pt}` instead of `\hline` (change `1pt` to the desired value).
- The `\Cline` command is similar to `\cline`, but has a mandatory argument allowing to specify the rule thicknes: `\Cline{<length>}{<column1>-<column2>}`; for example `\Cline{2pt}{2-4}` draws a horizontal rule `2pt` thick spanning columns 2 to 4.
- The `tabularx` package was used to guarantee that the table width equals `\columnwidth`. A new column type was defined with centered contents; `\tabularxcolumn` was also redefined to obtain `m{...}` type columns.
- The rotated text was produced using a `\parbox` inside a `\rotatebox`.

Notice, however, that your table goes against some rules of typography: vertical rules can be avoided and rotated text is not a good practice (thinking on the reader). Perhaps you could try reformulating the layout?

Here's a possibility without vertical rules and with the features provided by [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\RotText[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2cm}{\raggedright#1}}}
\begin{document}

{
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{YYYYYYYYYY}
\cmidrule[1pt]{2-10}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Some text}  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Some text} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-2}\cmidrule(r){3-3}\cmidrule(r){4-4}\cmidrule(r){5-5}
\cmidrule(r){6-6}\cmidrule(r){7-7}\cmidrule(r){8-8}\cmidrule(r){9-9}\cmidrule{10-10}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \RotText{Some really long text} & \RotText{Some really long text}
  & \RotText{Some really long text} & \RotText{Some really long text} 
  & \RotText{Some really long text} & \RotText{Some really long text} 
  & \RotText{Some really long text} & \RotText{Some really long text} 
  & \RotText{Some really long text} \\
\cmidrule[1pt](r){1-1}\cmidrule[1pt](r){2-6}\cmidrule[1pt]{7-10}
some text & 11 & 44 & 11 & 54 & 34 & 54 & 23 & 11 & 12 \\
some text & 11 & 44 & 11 & 54 & 34 & 54 & 23 & 11 & 12 \\
\bottomrule[1pt]
\end{tabularx}
}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do the following?:  I want that first vertical line to be thick also and I don't know how to do it.
I also want the horizontal line below the columns 2-9 to be bold.

Comment: @sphere please see my updated answer. Is it something like that what you want?

Comment: Thank you, but I wanted the horizontal border above  the far left column to be normal, not thick, how do you do that?  Also, I wanted the text centered please.

Comment: @sphere which text should be centered?

Comment: The text for all cells. As in the original picture I posted.

Comment: @sphere and isn't like that in my first example code?

Comment: No, the text in the vertical columns is aligned with the bottom. I haven't tried your code, just going by the picture you posed.

Comment: @sphere Ah, I see. Please see my updated answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: Damn, i made a mistake. I wanted the only the right side of the first column to have a bold border. So Column 2 row 1 should not have a bold left border.  Also it appears that the thin border and thick border to not match up well (i.e the horizontal top border of the far left column doesn't match up well with the thick border it runs into starting on the second column).

Comment: @sphere Any other changes? I don't want to spend more time fixing things on this.

Comment: That is all. I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @sphere please see this image: http://i.imgur.com/brb3X2r.png Is that the desired result?

Comment: Hmm, I'm starting to think it looks terrible now. I might just go through and hack your answer to my specifications. The problem I see is that the thick lines don't meet up with the thin lines well. Do you know what I am talking about?

Comment: @sphere yes, I know what you're talking about. I think thick lines should span the whole table instead of having one part thin, one thick on the same rule.

Comment: Yes, I'll do it that way

Comment: @sphere Do you mind then if I change the code again, to change the "mixed" rule to be all thick again?

Comment: You did that already, yes?

Comment: If so, I think it looks nice

Comment: @sphere yes, I did it. I also thinks it looks better this way.

Comment: Last thing I promise, when I add my text in the left hand column, it doesn't fit and runs into the second column. How do I make the first column wider?

Comment: @sphere instead of `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{YYYYYYYYYY}` use something like `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{>{\centering}p{3cm}YYYYYYYYY}` (use the desired length instead of `3cm`).

Comment: Hah, figured it out. Thank you. I realized a sec ago that just replace Y with my own newcolumntype with a specified width. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @GonzaloMedina, this is the table I am referring to. In my actual table, the "Some text" rows at the top actually contain more text (such that they need to wrap).  So in order to reproduce my situation, those rows need extra text. Then what the problem is is that the text was reduced, but now the top horizontal border now hits the text in that first row.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10123/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-sphere)

Comment: @sphere please follow the link above to continue in chat. I left some code there for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\noindent
{\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}
 [hvlines,corners=NW,cell-space-limits=1pt]
 {c|[tikz=very thick]*{5}{X[c]}|[tikz=very thick]*{5}{X[c]}}
  & \Block{1-5}{Some text} &&&&& \Block{1-4}{Some text} \\
  \RowStyle{\rotate[c]}
  & \Block{}{Some really\\ long text} 
  & \Block{}{Some really\\ long text} 
  & \Block{}{Some really\\ long text} 
  & \Block{}{Some really\\ long text} 
  & \Block{}{Some really\\ long text} 
  & \Block{}{Some really\\ long text} 
  & \Block{}{Some really\\ long text} 
  & \Block{}{Some really\\ long text} 
  & \Block{}{Some really\\ long text} \\
  \Hline[tikz=very thick]
  \Block{}{\,some\\ text} & 11 & 14 & 11 & 54 & 34 & 54 & 23 & 11 & 12 \\
\end{NiceTabular}}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]